# Create SQL Query for Name/Value Pair Data

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have data stored in a table like the one below, and I need to rearrange it. Theres a limited amount of "FieldName" entries. These should go as Header for the "FieldValue" Data. The data is stored in an Excel Workbook for further use.  I don't have the possibility to change the way data is stored and/or redesign the table.

```
ID | Source | FieldName | FieldValue  
--------------------------------------------
1  | EMail  | From      | Sender
1  | EMail  | To        | Receiver
1  | EMail  | Subject   | Whatever
2  | EMail  | From      | Another Sender
2  | EMail  | To        | Another Receiver
2  | EMail  | Subject   | Other Text
3  | Letter | From      | 3rd Sender
3  | Letter | To        | asdg
3  | Letter | Subject   | odasda
```

This is what the final table should look like.

```
ID | Source | From           | To               | Subject
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | EMail  | Sender         | Receiver         | Whatever
2  | EMail  | Another Sender | Another Receiver | Other Text
3  | Letter | 3rd Sender     | asdg             | odasda
```

The purpose of this is that - by having the data like this - i can join the data by ID onto other data.

At the moment, I'm rearranging the data after running the query with vba in my Excel Workbook, but this feels kind of non-performant.

Does anyone have some idea how to solve it? I didn't find anything after googling a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation like this:

```
SELECT t.id,t.source
       max(CASE WHEN t.fieldname = 'From' then t.FieldValue end) as From_col,
       max(CASE WHEN t.fieldname = 'To' then t.FieldValue end) as To_col,
       max(CASE WHEN t.fieldname = 'Subject' then t.FieldValue end) as Subject_col
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.id,t.source
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank's for the Inspiration, that's what I needed

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,
  source,
  MAX(DECODE(fieldname,'From',FieldValue)) f_From,
  MAX(DECODE(fieldname,'To',FieldValue)) f_To ,
  MAX(DECODE(fieldname,'Subject',FieldValue)) f_Subject
FROM table
GROUP BY id,
  source;
```